# Performance Issue in Entity Framework Database first approach

Tags: entity-framework

I have windows form application which uses database first approach of entity framework. Application is being used to read txt files of 50,000 rows. Each rows has 20 values and for each value we have some business rules which required to validate from database values and then insert those values in 4-5 different tables 
So there are minimum 50 database calls we have in our code for each row.

Initially I faced "out of memory" exception and because of that I was not able to run the txt file above 500 rows. Now I fixed that issue and application is running fine. But it is taking more time when I try with more number of rows. Like for 500 rows(3.5 mins), 1000 rows(10 mins) & 2000 rows(30 mins).

I would like to know whether context object holds the data every time when I insert into database. and why it is taking more time for simple (select query) lambda expression when row count goes above 500.

Appreciate your response/comments/suggestions.

Note:
1) We have around 15-20 tables.
2) One edmx file with some custom classes.
3) Context and edmx file resides in different class library and we are using it as dll reference.

Thanks in advance. 
Manoj

Comment: " Like for 500 rows(3.5 mins), 1000 rows(10 mins) & 2000 rows(30 mins)." - if I were a betting man, I'd say you have a double loop somewhere, but without seeing your code its just a guess...

Comment: we don't have any loop, only thing is that each row is running through  some rule and have database interaction. minimum 50 database transactions per row. due to security constraints I cannot post the code and it is on separate machine.